# sfml network, online game

Tags: c++, сеть, sfml

Всем привет, решил сделать онлайн мини игру, управление квадратами, на библиотеке sfml, сервер, и клиент сделал, все работает, может подключаться сразу несколько игроков, но квадраты не двигаются... помогите пожалуйста в чем проблема
вот коды:

Клиент:

```
#include <string>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    IpAddress ip = "25.22.222.120";
    TcpSocket socket;
    string id;

    cout << "Введите id: ";
    cin >> id;

    socket.connect(ip, 1111);

    RenderWindow Window(VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Valakas");

    vector<RectangleShape> rects;

    Packet packet;
    packet << id;
    socket.send(packet);
    socket.setBlocking(false);

    Window.setTitle(id);

    RectangleShape rect;
    rect.setSize(Vector2f(20, 20));
    rect.setFillColor(Color::Red);
    rects.push_back(rect);
    RectangleShape temprect;
    temprect.setFillColor(Color::Blue);
    temprect.setSize(Vector2f(20, 20));
    rects.push_back(temprect);
    Vector2f prevPosition, p2Position;

    while(Window.isOpen()) {
        Event event;
        while (Window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case Event::Closed:
                Window.close();
                break;
            case Event::KeyPressed:
                if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Escape)
                    Window.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        prevPosition = rect.getPosition();

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
            rect.move(-0.5f, 0.0f);
        }
        else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) {
            rects.front().move(0.5f, 0.0f);
        }
        else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W)) {
            rect.move(0.0f, -0.5f);
        }
        else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S)) {
            rect.move(0.0f, -0.5f);
        }

        Packet packet;

        if(prevPosition != temprect.getPosition()) {
        packet << rect.getPosition().x << rect.getPosition().y;
        socket.send(packet);
        }

        socket.receive(packet);

        if (packet >> p2Position.x >> p2Position.y) {
            temprect.setPosition(p2Position);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
            Window.draw(rects[i]);
        }

        Window.display();
        Window.clear();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Сервер:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    TcpListener listener;
    SocketSelector selector;
    vector<TcpSocket*> clients;

    listener.listen(1111);
    selector.add(listener);

    while (true) {
        if (selector.wait()) {
            if (selector.isReady(listener)) {
                TcpSocket *socket = new TcpSocket;
                listener.accept(*socket);
                Packet packet;
                string id;
                if (socket->receive(packet) == Socket::Done)
                    packet >> id;
                cout << id << " присоединился" << endl;
                clients.push_back(socket);
                selector.add(*socket);
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
                    if (selector.isReady(*clients[i])) {
                        Packet packet, sendPacket;
                        if (clients[i]->receive(packet) == Socket::Done) {
                            int x, y;
                            packet >> x >> y;
                            cout << x << " " << y;
                            sendPacket << x << y;
                            for (int j = 0; j < clients.size(); j++) {
                                if (i != j)
                                    clients[j]->send(sendPacket);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(vector<TcpSocket*>::iterator it = clients.begin(); it != clients.end(); it++)
        delete *it;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Буду очень признателен, благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Первое что бросилось в глаза. Вы обращаетесь к вектору, только в одном случае, в остальных случаях. Вы обращаетесь к объекту, который мог быть скопирован при добавлении в вектор - соответственно изменения на элементы вектора не применяются.

```
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
        rect.move(-0.5f, 0.0f);
    }
    else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) {
        rects.front().move(0.5f, 0.0f);
    }
    else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W)) {
        rect.move(0.0f, -0.5f);
    }
    else if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S)) {
        rect.move(0.0f, -0.5f);
    }
```

Второе что мне не нравится

```
 Window.display();
 Window.clear();
```

Вы сначала включаете отображение, а потом очищаете окно, я бы сделал вызов clear перед циклом отрисовки.